# Can I generate links from the name of files?

Tags: html, jquery, file, hyperlink

Can you help me with this question? Lets say I have a html document in a certain folder. Then I upload a file in the same folder, lets say a pdf. And lets say I name the file "grab_document.pdf". Is there a jquery command to make the -tag search for "grab" in the folder, recognize the file and then grab the name of the file and use it? Like (I am absolutely clueless):

<a href="$(grab file in folder beginning with the letters "grab")">document

That would help me to upload files without touching the html... I hope.

Thank you!
Andre

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. $("a[href|='grab']") - It selects all anchor tags with a href attribute value equal to 'grab', or starting with 'grab' followed by a hyphen.
2. $("a[href^='grab']") - All anchor tags with a href attribute value starting with 'grab'.

Hope it helps you!